# Change highlight color for a specific item (QAction type) on a QMenuBar

Tags: qt, pyside2, qmenubar

I want to mimic the behavior of the window top-right corner actions when hovering over the minimize-maximize-close buttons.

[image]
[image]

So I have created a QMenuBar that contains 3 QActions.

```
class WindowMenuActions(QMenuBar):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowMenuActions, self).__init__()
        minimize_action = QAction(self)
        minimize_action.setIcon(_MINIMIZE_ICON)

        maximize_action = QAction(self)
        maximize_action.setIcon(_MAXIMIZE_ICON)

        exit_action = QAction(self)
        exit_action.setIcon(_CLOSE_ICON)
        
        self.addAction(minimize_action)
        self.addAction(maximize_action)
        self.addAction(exit_action)
```

And set the background color when hovering with stylesheet (it is applied to the entire QApplication):

I want the close button to have a different highlight color, so I tried setting a boolean property on the exit_action to change the color only for that specific item, but it does not do any effect (in fact, if I add the property in the stylesheet it doesn't even consider the stylesheet values)

Any idea of how to achieve this?
To extend the question, I would not only use this for the minimize-maximize-close actions, but also to understand how to apply different hover/selected colors on QActions in the QMenuBar (not in the QMenu, which I already found a solution for that).

This is an running example:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMenuBar, QAction, QStyle, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt


class WindowMenuActions(QMenuBar):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowMenuActions, self).__init__()
        minimize_action = QAction(self)

        _MINIMIZE_ICON = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarMinButton)
        _MAXIMIZE_ICON = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarMaxButton)
        _EXIT_ICON = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarCloseButton)

        minimize_action.setIcon(_MINIMIZE_ICON)
        minimize_action.setProperty('exit_action', False)

        maximize_action = QAction(self)
        maximize_action.setProperty('exit_action', False)
        maximize_action.setIcon(_MAXIMIZE_ICON)

        exit_action = QAction(self)
        exit_action.setProperty('exit_action', True)
        exit_action.setIcon(_EXIT_ICON)

        self.addAction(minimize_action)
        self.addAction(maximize_action)
        self.addAction(exit_action)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            'QMenuBar::item:selected {'
                'background-color: grey;'
            '}'
            'QMenuBar::item[exit_action=true]:selected {'
                ' background-color: red;'
            '}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = QMainWindow()
    main.setMenuBar(WindowMenuActions())
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone interested, I sorted by inheriting from a regular QWidget instead of a QMenuBar and using QToolButton instead of QAction.

Working example:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMenuBar, QStyle, QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QToolButton, QMenu
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

class MenuBar(QMenuBar):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MenuBar, self).__init__()

        self.addMenu(QMenu('File'))
        self.addMenu(QMenu('Help'))
        self.setCornerWidget(WindowMenuActions(self))


class WindowMenuActions(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WindowMenuActions, self).__init__(parent)

        _MINIMIZE_ICON = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarMinButton)
        _MAXIMIZE_ICON = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarMaxButton)
        _EXIT_ICON = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TitleBarCloseButton)

        minimize = QToolButton(self)
        minimize.setIcon(_MINIMIZE_ICON)

        maximize = QToolButton(self)
        maximize.setIcon(_MAXIMIZE_ICON)

        exit_action = QToolButton(self)
        exit_action.setProperty('exit_button', True)
        exit_action.setIcon(_EXIT_ICON)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(minimize)
        layout.addWidget(maximize)
        layout.addWidget(exit_action)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setStyleSheet(
            'QToolButton:hover {'
                ' background: grey;'
            '}'
            'QToolButton[exit_button=true]:hover {'
            ' background: red;'
            '}'
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = QMainWindow()
    main.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    main.setMenuBar(MenuBar())
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Be aware that menubar supports compression, meaning that if the parent becomes narrower than the menubar size hint, some actions will be hidden and only available via the extension button, and the corner widget can also become partially hidden, since the layout doesn't consider the menu minimum size. Also, although you changed the approach, consider that not all styles support action icons in QMenuBar, with some styles completely ignoring them or drawing only when hovered. Finally, `addMenu(QMenu)` doesn't take ownership of the QMenu, so it might be destroyed afterwards if it has no parent.

Comment: Thanks! is there any better approach you can think of?